# Unable to apply styles through DOM for renderAs pdf pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, css

I have a page .I'm using it as pdf page.I made some css changes using jQuery.Without using renderAs="pdf" tag ,everything is working fine.But if I use renderAs="pdf" tag, the changes through DOM are not applicable.I'm using API version 35.0 .If I use css using style tag, there are working.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <html>
        <head>
           <!-- <style>
                body { font-size: 1em;color:red; }
                h1 { text-align: center; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal;color:red; }
                hr.seperator { margin: 10px auto 5px quto; width: 50%; color: #000; background-color: #000; height:1px; border: none;color:red; }
                h5 { text-align: center; margin: 0; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal;color:red; }
                p { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; color:red;}
                p.proclamation { font-size: 1.3em; font-style: italic;color:red; }
            </style>-->

        </head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#a").css({"color":"yellow"});
        });
        </script>
        <apex:form >
            <h1 id="a">POWER OF ATTORNEY</h1>
            <hr class="seperator"/>
            <h5>Erasures and Alterations void this instrument</h5>
            <h5>This instrument void after sixty days from date herein</h5>
            <br />
            <p class="proclamation">Know All Men By These Presents, That I, the undersigned, do hereby make, constitute and appoint</p>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <p>Address:</p>
            <p>My true and lawful attorney-in-fact for the following described motor vehicle, to-wit:</p>
            <p><span>Make</span><span>Year</span><span>Serial No.</span></p>
        </apex:form>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Please tell me the way, How to apply styles through jQuery in renderAs="pdf" pages.

Comment: you can't use jQuery or javascript  in rendered as pdf.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for my problem?

Comment: hey @manoj check my ans use only  css selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use jQuery or javascript in rendered as pdf.

Use only

```
<style>
#a{
color:yellow;
}
<style>
```

instead of jq

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#a").css({"color":"yellow"});
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Rathan. I think this is the only way to achieve this.